# Convert text to key presses

Tags: code-golf, keyboard

I am a robot. I bought [this keyboard](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41P-kEz89OL._SX355_.jpg) because of its easy rectangular layout:

```
~`   !1   @2   #3   $4   %5   ^6   &7   *8   (9   )0   _-   +=
tab  Qq   Ww   Ee   Rr   Tt   Yy   Uu   Ii   Oo   Pp   {[   }]    \|
     Aa   Ss   Dd   Ff   Gg   Hh   Jj   Kk   Ll   :;   "'   [-enter-]
          Zz   Xx   Cc   Vv   Bb   Nn   Mm   <,   >.   ?/
                         [========= space =========]
```

To print human text, I need to convert it to commands that my manipulators can interpret. My left manipulator hovers over the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. My right manipulator, at the beginning, hovers over the <kbd>~</kbd> key. The commands that my manipulators understand are:

```
S      : press the shift key
s      : release the shift key
L      : move the right manipulator left by 1
R      : move the right manipulator right by 1
U      : move the right manipulator up by 1
D      : move the right manipulator down by 1
P      : press the key under the right manipulator
p      : release the key by the right manipulator
```

Write code to convert any ASCII message to a list of commands. The input can contain any number of the 95 printable ASCII characters; possibly also TAB and newline characters. The output should be the list of the commands to the manipulators.

So, for example, to type `Hello World!`, the commands are

```
SRRRRRRDDPp
sLLLUPp
RRRRRRDPp
Pp
UPp
LLLLDDDPp
SLLLUUUPp
sRRRRRRRPp
LLLLLPp
RRRRRDPp
LLLLLLPp
SLLUUPp
```

I reset the manipulators to initial state before printing each message.

There are some mechanical hazards that should be avoided by proper programming:

1. No moving (`LRUD`) allowed when printing (`P`) is engaged
2. No jamming of manipulators: when a manipulator is engaged (`S` or `P`), the next command for this manipulator should be disengaging (`s` or `p`), and vice-versa
3. No unnecessary shifting: between each two shift (`s`, `S`) commands, there should be a `P` command

   So, to print `~~`, commands `SPpPp` are valid, while `SPpsSPp` are not
4. No moving out of bounds: no movement command should try to move the right manipulator more than 13 spaces to the right or 4 to the bottom of the initial position (or any spot to the top or left)

Additional notes:

- Pressing a disabled key (command sequence like `DDPp`) results in no keys pressed and is allowed.
- Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> has no effect, but <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> have the same effect as without <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
- Pressing on any spot on the space bar and the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key has the same effect.
- Whitespace keys in output have no meaning, but can be used to format it in a beautiful way.

Comment: Is speed a problem? Could we return the manipulators to their home position between each character (so long as it doesn't include unnecessary shifting, of course)?

Comment: No problem. Maybe it could be more interesting without extra movement, but I don't like requiring the best possible output.

Comment: [Related one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/77510/42963), [related two](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/100539/42963).

Comment: You haven't actually defined the task... What character can input contain? What _is_ the actual task (I'm going to guess it's the obvious based on the title, but you should specify nonetheless)

Comment: It seems a person typing on a On Screen Keyboard of a Smart TV using its remote control! I feel I do the same when it is me! Was it your inspiration?

Comment: Actually, my inspiration was trying to type while all my fingers except two are smeared with mud. But a Smart TV seems more mainstream!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/161719/58563) with a simpler output but more strict constraints.

Comment: Why bother with `Pp`? As far as I can see those are always a single action and neither `P` or `p` can appear on its own.

Comment: Pp and Ss look more robotic. I imagine a simple controller inserting delays between commands and connecting commands to electrical motors after simple parsing.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>338</s> <s>337</s> <s>335</s> <s>331</s> 325 bytes

````````python
x=y=s=0
for c in input():p='`1234567890-=`	qwertyuiop[]|`asdfghjkl;\'\n```zxcvbnm,./``````` ~!@#$%^&*()_+~~QWERTYUIOP{}\\~ASDFGHJKL:"\n~~~ZXCVBNM<>?~~~~~~~ '.find(c);S=[p>61,s][c in' \n'];p%=62;Y=p/14;X=[max(x,12),min(max(x,5),10),p%14]['\n '.find(c)];print'sS'[S]*(s^S)+'LR'[X>x]*abs(X-x)+'UD'[Y>y]*abs(Y-y)+'Pp';x,y,s=X,Y,S
````````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5bV4JAAISf61egZQu6qJBaSUs3Kysrk0xowfCaFC4bYEGX/etEh4fmzMt858ycoXG48IicJBGKUYCq63PP5yacQ1LTVcgLTYqALcnbtXpjZ3evKiJ77e1j5ofxyvEotr7tUTCdPy9eXl3FBCaxbfszmryPyRKWK3YmjuUONzYLw60iLzyVGLsbnPbujf7FbffrxzTZkdY6O29fXnWaeZMwxh71k4fjm@t99YBl4kB57pApPxEUDWGqNiQYWPjvJOBMAiyFFlBDVgxEK1JN0RFejiI@gpIswKVD@CzVBShVBUgLUs3C6dH/0bTvOyQEgQawZhX5YKgJJdDpAayrkVUcjQNeF6MU9VsAG2qcIUOMU9SlQIlgDAOkQwNqSZJvz1zX4wae705z@V8)

---

Moves directly from each character to the next.

Explanation:

- `S=[c in K,s][c in' \n']`, checks if the next character should be Upper- or lowercase. If `c` is a space or newline, the case remains the same.
- `X=[max(x,12),min(max(x,5),10),p%15]['\n '.find(c)]`. If `c` is a space or newline, the closest x-coordinate to the current is chosen(as the keys span multiple columns)
- `print'sS'[S]*(s!=S)+'LR'[X>x]*abs(X-x)+'UD'[Y>y]*abs(Y-y)+'Pp'`, prints the case switch, the number of x-coordinate moves, the number of y-coordinate moves, and finally `Pp`, for each character

---

Shorter version, if the shortest path is not required:

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>294</s> <s>293</s> <s>291</s> <s>287</s> 281 bytes

````````python
x=y=s=0
for c in input():p='`1234567890-=`	qwertyuiop[]|`asdfghjkl;\'\n```zxcvbnm,./``````` ~!@#$%^&*()_+~~QWERTYUIOP{}\\~ASDFGHJKL:"\n~~~ZXCVBNM<>?~~~~~~~ '.find(c);S=[p>61,s][c in' \n'];p%=62;X,Y=p%14,p/14;print'sS'[S]*(s^S)+'LR'[X>x]*abs(X-x)+'UD'[Y>y]*abs(Y-y)+'Pp';x,y,s=X,Y,S
````````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY/bVoJAAEWf6yvIogEdUcispKGb3a1MsiAGG8VMugwTgwVd5teJlnudp/1w1jksS6YRNfI8RRniqL44iWIpkEJahM0SRW0xBIhurDXWmxubW/UqIgvvn49xks3CiHn@Dxny8eRp@vzyamKAKSHkKw0@RvQNajUyRxJLu8sr8mC1rKgPFSGu7w57N27/9Kr7/Yux2LPbR8cnZ@edVglTIcS9c3C7f3mxbe2IORLQJiEdK4Fq2shjVlOH3Pf@RwIJU@CbTEZNw3Sgi5isNyCr6Q2TxSFNALeBZ/tlhQ9stQI6PeA5VuqXhyOuONW0UP028Fwrmyu3mhWqy4CZwgxyVDRCO89LmmRhihNRHC/9AQ)

Comment: Is it really required to use the shortest path to `space` / `enter`?

Comment: @Arnauld, I guest not, it wasn't specified but the example goes to the nearest space (after `o`)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 263 bytes

Takes input as an array of characters.

```javascript
s=>s.map(c=>(y=i-(i=(j=`\`~1!2@3#4$5%6^7&8*9(0)-_=+00\t0qQwWeErRtTyYuUiIoOpP[{]}|\\00aAsSdDfFgGhHjJkKlL;:'"
${1e6}zZxXcCvVbBnNmM,<.>/?${1e13} `.indexOf(c))>>1),g=k=>'LRUD'[n=k?y/14:y%14,k^=n<0].repeat(n<0?-n:n))()+g(2)+['sS'[j-s&c!=' '&c!=`
`?s^=1:2]]+'Pp',i=s=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcnbVoJAAEDRd79CS52ZgBHUrMiBLlZWVqaZFWAQt7gIxJBJZr9O@XT2Wsc3FgY1Uy/JuCi27MIhBSUSxXMjgSaRYE48DnoE@kRX9V@h0jxqbberu7XObK@@v3MAecS9Eobn1Yz/uP@a2mfpKHvInz8n3mV8lwyVlbb@UVWeN47p2Oo55@7Fe9@/Cq7DwaEItkrVlWB31t8vyyfzdPH4dhLdzm/YLpYa8uYIrXVZx15k2cs7B5oISZKAWJcERAKD0aQHlIgEct4Q2mJeE9psMCNRl9dwaie2kcF/y1wkRghBxLiwiRgF0DFQfI7WzQoBZbCJXtJlOiOC2NQ0BgwTwHqEEh4VZhzROLRxGLvQgQrGGPTtMIzL0zgNrQrQECr@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## .COM opcode, <s>108</s> 104 bytes

```
0000h: B4 00 CD 16 BE 50 01 83 C6 03 3A 24 77 F9 0F B6
0010h: DC 03 5C 01 B4 02 CD 16 B4 02 68 00 01 A8 03 B2
0020h: 53 74 08 81 36 20 01 20 01 CD 21 84 DB 74 0B 4B
0030h: B2 52 E8 F4 FF B2 4C CD 21 C3 84 FF 74 0C FE CF
0040h: B2 44 E8 E4 FF B2 55 CD 21 C3 B2 50 CD 21 B2 70
0050h: CD 21 C3 0D FE 00 1B F1 00 1C F0 01 28 E3 01 29
0060h: D7 FF 35 D6 02 39 CC 03
```

Take input from keyboard with CapsLock off

Badly golfed though

```
        org 100h
        mov ah, 0
        int 16H
        mov si, table-3
tabing: add si, 3
        cmp ah, [si]
        ja tabing
        movzx bx, ah
        add bx, [si+1]
        mov ah, 2
        int 16H
        mov ah, 2
        push 100H
        test al, 3
        mov dl, 'S'
cmd:    jz fun
        xor [cmd-1], word 0x120
        int 21H
fun:    test bl, bl
        jz bl0
        dec bx
        mov dl, 'R'
        int 21H
        call fun
        mov dl, 'L'
        int 21H
        ret
bl0:    test bh, bh
        jz bh0
        dec bh
        mov dl, 'D'
        int 21H
        call fun
        mov dl, 'U'
        int 21H
        ret
bh0:    mov dl, 'P'
        int 21H
        mov dl, 'p'
        int 21H
        ret
macro key begin, end, U, L {
        db end
        dw U*256+L-begin
}
table:
        key 0x02, 0x0D, 1, 0
        key 0x10, 0x1B, 1, 1
        key 0x1C, 0x1C, 2, 12
        key 0x1E, 0x28, 2, 1
        key 0x29, 0x29, 0, 0
        key 0x2C, 0x35, 3, 2
        key 0x39, 0x39, 4, 5
```

Comment: A great idea to do that without a LUT!

Comment: `Take input from keyboard`

How is our robot friend, who is asking for help using his keyboard, to make use of this program?